# how to access value of a learned parameter of an activation function in a sequential network

Tags: pytorch

I am implementing my custom activation function with learnable parameters. For example this can be similar to PReLu https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.PReLU.html which a learnable parameter `a`.

How can I access/view the a parameter value after training ?

*Solution* the issue was related to the fact that it was a sequential network and this helped solve the issue https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/access-weights-of-a-specific-module-in-nn-sequential/3627

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is blocking you ? Your learnable parameter is an attribute of your custom activation function class, so you can access it like any other attribute in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`nn.PReLU`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.PReLU.html) layer is a [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html), like most other layers you can access the weights directly using the `weight` property.

```
>>> act = nn.PReLU()
>>> act.weight
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.2500], requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: thanks, the issue was related to the fact that it was a sequential network and this helped solve the issue https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/access-weights-of-a-specific-module-in-nn-sequential/3627